# "Typedef redefinition with different types" error in Clang on working MSVC code

Tags: c++, xcode4, scope, clang, typedef

I've been given some code that compiles fine on MSVC, and I'm trying to get it to compile on Clang in Xcode. I'm currently coming across an issue where a class is being redefined using the following typedef:

```
typedef std::map<MyNS::istring, EntityState> Entity;
```

Looking at the preprocessed output, I can see that there are two forward declarations of `class Entity` before this typedef. However, the actual definition of `class Entity` is not in the preprocessed output, but it is in the same namespace as the new Entity map (not `MyNS` though...). Is it the forward declarations that are causing this error? And is there some way that this could be valid in MSVC and not working due to the pedantry of Clang?

EDIT: I don't have MSVC to hand, but here's a snippet I put together to demonstrate the kind of error I'm getting (I've simplified the definitions so that it all fits in a small space). This causes the same error as I get when I try to compile it with Clang. Would this work in MSVC?

```
namespace TheNS {

    class Entity;

    struct EntityState
    {
        std::string aString, anotherString;
        int anInt;

        EntityState() {}

        EntityState(std::string a, std::string b, int i)
        {
            // constructor
        }
    };

    typedef std::map<std::string, EntityState> Entity;

    class Entity
    {
    public:
        void SomeFunction();

    private:
        int m_aVar;

    };

}
```

Comment: There is namespace, in which there is forward declaration of class Entity and typedef on std::map with same name, yeah?

Comment: There is a forward declaration of `class Entity` in one of the included files, and there is a class definition of `class Entity` in the same namespace as the typedef but not in one of the included files (i.e. doesn't show up in the preprocessed output).

Comment: Why don't you post all the declarations of `Entity` (and the namespace the declarations show up in)? Even better if the snippet that you post can be compiled with clang to produce the error you're seeing (and ideally no error on MSVC). I'm having a hard time puzzling though the description in the question.

Comment: Forward declaration is in the same namespace as typedef? Show them please.

Comment: Do you mean: https://ideone.com/ganOc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's not correct. Should never compile, if it compiles on MSVC - probably it's a bug of compiler. Forward declaration tells compiler, that `TheNS::Entity` will be class and nothing else (not enum, union, or typedef). Really, your code is same as

```
class Entity;   
typedef int Entity;
```

Of course it's incorrect.

n3337 9.1/2

> A declaration consisting solely of class-key identifier; is either a redeclaration of the name
> in the current scope or a forward declaration of the identifier as a class name. It introduces the class name
> into the current scope.

So, after this

```
class Entity;
```

compiles knows, that `Entity` will be used as class-name. This name can be redeclared as function (in the same scope), in this case you should use `class Entity`, when you want to use `Entity` class (or redeclare `Entity` name by typedef as says in comments).

7.1.3/6

> In a given scope, a typedef specifier shall not be used to redefine the name of any type declared in that
> scope to refer to a different type. [ Example:
>
> ```
> class complex { /∗ ... ∗/ };
> typedef int complex; // error: redifinition
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Comment: `typedef struct Entity Entity;` ;)